# How do I move the exit button below the fan?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, positioning

Can you help me?

Currently the red exit button is on the spinning fan, I want to place it below it.

How do I do that in the code? https://jsfiddle.net/aqpoew6d/

I am trying to do this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0plg.png)

```
.exit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47px;
  height: 47px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 5px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 1;
  clip-path: circle(50%);
}

.exit::before,
.exit::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  width: 47px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -5px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.exit::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.exit::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgfaB.png)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: gray;
}

.containerInitial {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 255px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.curtainInitial {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 680px;
  border: 21px solid;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.curtainInitial::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, transparent 0% 48.5%, #0a0a0a 48.5%);
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
}

.curtainInitial::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  outline: 1px solid green;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.fence {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background:
    linear-gradient(45deg,
      #0000 7px,
      #0a0a0a 0 7.5px,
      #0000 0 10px),
    linear-gradient(-45deg,
      #0000 7px,
      #0a0a0a 0 7.5px,
      #0000 0 10px),
  linear-gradient(to top, #e10019 0%, #957e00 100%);
  background-size: 10px 10px,10px 10px, cover;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #000);
  -webkit-animation: fade 5s infinite;
  animation: fade 5s infinite;
  clip-path: circle(34.5% at center);
}

.fence>div {
  position: absolute;
  /*top: 0;*/
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  height: 0.55%;
  /*height: 2px;*/
  background: black;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(1) {
  top: 9.8%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(2) {
  top: 19.2%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(3) {
  top: 28.6%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(4) {
  top: 38%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(5) {
  top: 47.4%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(6) {
  top: 56.8%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(7) {
  top: 66.2%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(8) {
  top: 75.6%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(9) {
  top: 85%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(10) {
  top: 94.4%;
}

.fan svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.cross {
  clip-path: circle(34.5% at center);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}

.cross::before,
.cross::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: black;
}

.cross::before
/*horizontal*/
  {
  height: 2.8%;
}

.cross::after
/*vertical*/
  {
  width: 1.4%;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fan svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: fan-spin 40s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes fan-spin {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.98) rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(0.98) rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
}

iframe {
  display: block;
  animation: iframe 5s ease-in 5s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes iframe {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.embed-youtube iframe,
.embed-youtube .embed-youtube-play,
.embed-youtube .embed-youtube-play::before {
  position: absolute;
}

.embed-youtube iframe {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.exit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47px;
  height: 47px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 5px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 1;
  clip-path: circle(50%);
}

.exit::before,
.exit::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  width: 47px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -5px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.exit::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.exit::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="containerInitial ">
   <div class="curtainInitial">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
         <div class="fence">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fan">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70%" height="70%" viewBox="76 130 381 381">
               <g id="fan">
                  <title>Fan</title>
                  <path fill="#000100" stroke="#000"
                     d="m166.3352 168.6294c5.5396 2.4448 45.2339 54.394 72.7499 91.0151-9.1901-44.8757-21.7959-109.0279-19.9558-114.796 4.1462-12.9949 33.7039-13.5172 41.5845-13.7579 7.8827-.2415 37.4165-1.5221 42.3488 11.1948 2.1872 5.6436-6.4773 70.4506-12.9142 115.8007 25.2309-38.2323 61.6818-92.5089 67.0612-95.2865 12.119-6.2568 33.3898 14.2749 39.1337 19.6768 5.7424 5.402 27.5341 25.3815 22.0294 37.859-2.4441 5.5389-54.3954 45.2354-91.0172 72.7506 44.8757-9.1901 109.0293-21.7959 114.7974-19.9559 12.9927 4.1442 13.5193 33.7032 13.7586 41.5838.2422 7.8819 1.5221 37.4165-11.192 42.3473-5.6471 2.1894-70.4541-6.4765-115.8049-12.9127 38.2323 25.2323 92.5081 61.6783 95.2871 67.0605 6.2581 12.1175-14.2742 33.3877-19.6776 39.133-5.4027 5.7432-25.3815 27.5341-37.8563 22.0279-5.5396-2.4434-45.2361-54.3961-72.7534-91.0143 9.1901 44.8757 21.7952 109.0287 19.9551 114.7953-4.1434 12.9934-33.7026 13.5157-41.5852 13.7586-7.8799.24-37.4165 1.5221-42.3431-11.1936-2.1887-5.6464 6.4779-70.4541 12.9133-115.8071-25.2323 38.2323-61.6824 92.5124-67.0639 95.2908-12.1169 6.256-33.3891-14.2728-39.1337-19.6754-5.7432-5.4027-27.5313-25.383-22.0251-37.8578 2.4434-5.5396 54.394-45.2339 91.0136-72.7526-44.8764 9.1908-109.0266 21.7944-114.7967 19.9566-12.9934-4.1434-13.5171-33.7025-13.7586-41.5852-.2407-7.8806-1.5221-37.4165 11.1963-42.346 5.6443-2.1879 70.4498 6.4752 115.8 12.9121-38.233-25.2316-92.5081-61.6783-95.2865-67.0612-6.256-12.1169 14.2748-33.3913 19.6768-39.1337 5.4006-5.7438 25.3794-27.5333 37.8584-22.0272z" />
               </g>
            </svg>
         </div>
         <div class="cross"></div>
         <div class="wrap">
            <div class="video video-frame" data-id="CHahce95B1g"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="video-one"></div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" title="Exit" aria-label="Close"></button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

move button outside last div and change bottom on .exit  to -257px

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: gray;
}

.containerInitial {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 255px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.curtainInitial {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 680px;
  border: 21px solid;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.curtainInitial::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, transparent 0% 48.5%, #0a0a0a 48.5%);
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
}

.curtainInitial::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  outline: 1px solid green;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.fence {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background:
    linear-gradient(45deg,
      #0000 7px,
      #0a0a0a 0 7.5px,
      #0000 0 10px),
    linear-gradient(-45deg,
      #0000 7px,
      #0a0a0a 0 7.5px,
      #0000 0 10px),
  linear-gradient(to top, #e10019 0%, #957e00 100%);
  background-size: 10px 10px,10px 10px, cover;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #000);
  -webkit-animation: fade 5s infinite;
  animation: fade 5s infinite;
  clip-path: circle(34.5% at center);
}

.fence>div {
  position: absolute;
  /*top: 0;*/
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  height: 0.55%;
  /*height: 2px;*/
  background: black;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(1) {
  top: 9.8%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(2) {
  top: 19.2%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(3) {
  top: 28.6%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(4) {
  top: 38%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(5) {
  top: 47.4%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(6) {
  top: 56.8%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(7) {
  top: 66.2%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(8) {
  top: 75.6%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(9) {
  top: 85%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(10) {
  top: 94.4%;
}

.fan svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.cross {
  clip-path: circle(34.5% at center);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}

.cross::before,
.cross::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: black;
}

.cross::before
/*horizontal*/
  {
  height: 2.8%;
}

.cross::after
/*vertical*/
  {
  width: 1.4%;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fan svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: fan-spin 40s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes fan-spin {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.98) rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(0.98) rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
}

iframe {
  display: block;
  animation: iframe 5s ease-in 5s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes iframe {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.embed-youtube iframe,
.embed-youtube .embed-youtube-play,
.embed-youtube .embed-youtube-play::before {
  position: absolute;
}

.embed-youtube iframe {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.exit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  bottom: -275.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47px;
  height: 47px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 5px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 1;
  clip-path: circle(50%);
}

.exit::before,
.exit::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  width: 47px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -5px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.exit::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.exit::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="containerInitial ">
   <div class="curtainInitial">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
         <div class="fence">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fan">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70%" height="70%" viewBox="76 130 381 381">
               <g id="fan">
                  <title>Fan</title>
                  <path fill="#000100" stroke="#000"
                     d="m166.3352 168.6294c5.5396 2.4448 45.2339 54.394 72.7499 91.0151-9.1901-44.8757-21.7959-109.0279-19.9558-114.796 4.1462-12.9949 33.7039-13.5172 41.5845-13.7579 7.8827-.2415 37.4165-1.5221 42.3488 11.1948 2.1872 5.6436-6.4773 70.4506-12.9142 115.8007 25.2309-38.2323 61.6818-92.5089 67.0612-95.2865 12.119-6.2568 33.3898 14.2749 39.1337 19.6768 5.7424 5.402 27.5341 25.3815 22.0294 37.859-2.4441 5.5389-54.3954 45.2354-91.0172 72.7506 44.8757-9.1901 109.0293-21.7959 114.7974-19.9559 12.9927 4.1442 13.5193 33.7032 13.7586 41.5838.2422 7.8819 1.5221 37.4165-11.192 42.3473-5.6471 2.1894-70.4541-6.4765-115.8049-12.9127 38.2323 25.2323 92.5081 61.6783 95.2871 67.0605 6.2581 12.1175-14.2742 33.3877-19.6776 39.133-5.4027 5.7432-25.3815 27.5341-37.8563 22.0279-5.5396-2.4434-45.2361-54.3961-72.7534-91.0143 9.1901 44.8757 21.7952 109.0287 19.9551 114.7953-4.1434 12.9934-33.7026 13.5157-41.5852 13.7586-7.8799.24-37.4165 1.5221-42.3431-11.1936-2.1887-5.6464 6.4779-70.4541 12.9133-115.8071-25.2323 38.2323-61.6824 92.5124-67.0639 95.2908-12.1169 6.256-33.3891-14.2728-39.1337-19.6754-5.7432-5.4027-27.5313-25.383-22.0251-37.8578 2.4434-5.5396 54.394-45.2339 91.0136-72.7526-44.8764 9.1908-109.0266 21.7944-114.7967 19.9566-12.9934-4.1434-13.5171-33.7025-13.7586-41.5852-.2407-7.8806-1.5221-37.4165 11.1963-42.346 5.6443-2.1879 70.4498 6.4752 115.8 12.9121-38.233-25.2316-92.5081-61.6783-95.2865-67.0612-6.256-12.1169 14.2748-33.3913 19.6768-39.1337 5.4006-5.7438 25.3794-27.5333 37.8584-22.0272z" />
               </g>
            </svg>
         </div>
         <div class="cross"></div>
         <div class="wrap">
            <div class="video video-frame" data-id="CHahce95B1g"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="video-one"></div>
      </div>
      
   </div>
</div>
<button class="exit" type="button" title="Exit" aria-label="Close"></button>
```

Comment: That won't work, as the button doesn't stay and ends up floating off the screen.

Comment: What ends up happening is, when the browser window gets smaller, the exit button floats away. See Image: https://i.imgur.com/Kc2FhVh.png